# in some projects Intellisense doesn't work at all for me . why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[my vscode environment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdS9G.jpg)

the Intellisense doesn't work at all
just tried to test a short component about fetching with typescript and axios but I couldn't used Intellisense

This problem happening sometimes as I couldn't find the solution and had to open a new project in vs code and hope that doesn't happening again finally I wanna know the main reason